# How to construct a promise chain involving multiple dependence?

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to construct a promise chain as below. The arrows represent dependence: B needs the output of A; C needs the outputs of both A and B.

Since it is not simply a chain but is a net, I don't know how to do it in an elegant way. My idea is to let the output of B contain the output of A, and pass it all together to C through edge (B,C). I guess it's probably not the best way to do it because there should be some method by passing the result of A directly to C.

[image: AngularJS promise chain]

Comment: I see no reason for anything other than a linear chain

Comment: This question is really about promises, and could be implemented in any framework; it's not Angular.js specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to provide C with the independent promise results, try something like this

```
var promises = { a: A() };
promises.b = promises.a.then(function(a) {
    return B(a);
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    C(results.a, results.b);
});
```

Otherwise, I see no problem with

```
A().then(function(a) {
    B(a).then(function(b) {
        C(a, b);
    });
});
```

but really, these are just two ways of writing the same thing.

Comment: I think second one is much more self explanatory.

Comment: @FelixKling OP initially tagged as Angular.

Comment: Ah. Still, `Promise.all` is standard :)

Comment: @Phil , I think you forgot to add `return`...

Comment: @mido22 `return` where?

Comment: @Phil,  `return B(a).then...`, `return C(a, b);`,

Comment: @mido22 OP doesn't mention requiring anything further than processing C. Given the arbitrary and rather academic nature of the question, adding such implementation details is out of scope. So in other words, no, I did not *"forget to add `return`"*

Comment: @FelixKling: Standard `Promise.all` doesn't take objects however. It only operates on iterables.

Comment: @Bergi: Right, didn't realize this was an object.

Comment: @Bergi objects aren't iterable?

Comment: @Phil: Most of them, yes. Only array objects, iterators, and everything else with an <iterator> method are iterable. All objects are `Reflect.enumerate`able, though.